# How do I "cast" concrete types in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, standardsetcontroller, typecast

Apex StandardSetControllers are powerful. I love the ability to new one up and dump it on a page.

Here's a contrived example, where a `Contact` has many `Engagements` with ratings etc:

```
public with sharing class ContactEngagementViewerExtension {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController EngagementSetController {get; set;}

    public ContactEngagementViewerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.EngagementSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
            SELECT Id, Name
            FROM Engagement__c
            WHERE Contact__c = :controller.getId()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then it's super easy to do this kind of thing on the page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!EngagementSetController.Record}" var="engagement">
    <apex:column value="{!engagement['Name']}" />
    <apex:column value="{!engagement['Rating__c']}" />
    <apex:column value="{!engagement['IsSatisfied__c']}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:commandButton action="{!EngagementSetController.First}" />
<apex:commandButton action="{!EngagementSetController.Previous}" />
<apex:commandButton action="{!EngagementSetController.Next}" />
<apex:commandButton action="{!EngagementSetController.Last}" />
Page {!EngagementSetController.PageNumber}
```

But the cracks start to appear with `EngagementSetController.Record` being an SObject:

- we've lost compile-time checking of field names
- the dynamic dereference prevents `size` working on collections etc
- there's a lot of hairiness and inconsistency around how those values behave in formulae etc

**How do I get concrete `Engagement__c` (not `SObject`) behaviour without changing the Apex?**

Edit: founr one angle (not really a solution) using a custom Visualforce Component as a "casting filter" - you can hand in the reference then use the strongly typed argument inside it.

Comment: You can add a *typed* getter to your controller
    `public List<Engagement__c> getEngagements() {
        return (List<Engagement__c>) EngagementSetController.getRecords();
    }`
(i'm not responding exactly to your question but i don't see the need of not changing the apex)

Comment: The intention behind not changing the Apex is to avoid breaking encapsulation. @AkramG